# iOS Toolbar act like a tabbar

Tags: ios, objective-c, toolbar, tabbar

I have a tab bar for my main app and I want when I move to a specific view controller to have a toolbar that will act like a tab bar (as far as i understand i cannot have a second tab bar). What I mean: when I push to the specific view controller I hide the main tab bar and I have a navigation controller toolbar with five items. I want each item to navigate to other controllers and toolbar to remain on bottom of the screen and show the selected item.

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you can not use a second tab bar, I suggest you to use a `segmented control` and manage the view that is displayed to the user at time the segment changes. However, there might be design and interaction considerations about using a segmented control at the bottom of the screen.